# Is there a way to generate a HTML form from a Draft-7 JSON schema?

Tags: javascript, html, jsonschema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
  "title": "sample",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "image": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/link",
      "description": "Link to a PNG image"
    },
    "object_types": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/object_types",
      "description": "Object types supports."
    },
    "person": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/person",
      "description": "humans"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "link": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "href": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "uri"
        },
        "person": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/person"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "href"
      ]
    },
    "object_types": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/object_type",
        "description": "Each additional property is an object type."
      }
    },
    "object_type": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "doc": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/link",
          "description": "Link to the schema of the object type."
        },
        "fields": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/input_field",
            "description": "Each additional property describes an input field."
          }
        },
        "pollable": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "A hint for the client that polling for this object_type might produce objects containing new data."
        },
        "metadata": {
          "type": "object",
          "description": "Free form key-value pairs. Can contain additional metadata about the object_type, if anything is required by client."
        },
        "endpoint": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/link",
          "description": "Link to an endpoint that produces this object_type."
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "endpoint"
      ]
    },
    "input_field": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "regex": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Regular expression that can be used by client to capture valid inputs, from a text line or paragraph."
        },
        "capture_group": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "Which parentheses group of the regex captured text to be used."
        },
        "env": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "To be collected from client's Environment variables and send in the request."
        },
        "required": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "description": "A flag says if this input field is mandatory. If client knows this field then it can include in the request for better results."
        }
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "regex": {
          "required": [
            "capture_group"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "http_methods": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "DELETE",
        "GET",
        "HEAD",
        "OPTIONS",
        "PATCH",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "TRACE"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the sample JSON for which docson is not able to generate the HTML.
This is v7 of JSON-schema. It works for v4.

Maybe it has to do with the additional Properties key.
Is there any tool/package similar to docson to generate HTML for the JSON schema.

This is the sample JSON for which docson is not able to generate the HTML.
This is v7 of JSON-schema. It works for v4. M

Maybe it has to do with the additional Properties key.
Is there any tool/package similar to docson to generate HTML for the JSON schema.

This is the sample JSON for which docson is not able to generate the HTML.
This is v7 of JSON-schema. It works for v4.

Maybe it has to do with the additional Properties key.
Is there any tool/package similar to docson to generate HTML for the JSON schema.

Comment: Hi Makrand. Stackoverflow isn't the right place to ask this sort of question. You've already asked it on the JSON Schema google group, which is the RIGHT place. Feel free to join our friendly slack server too!

Comment: There are no known fully compliant good solutions to what you want. Believe me, I've looked, a LOT. This is the closest there is: https://github.com/adobe/jsonschema2md